# how to get value of substring and set with new value

Tags: javascript

I have the following string myString=

```
id="eyJjbGFpbSI6IHsidHlwZSI6ICJkb21haW4iLCAicm9sZSI6ICJ1c2VyOk", ts="1467847506", nonce="YTcdzC"
```

I want to get ts="1467847506" from this string and add 1467847506 + 3600 
and set it back ts="1467851106"

so the final myString is:

```
id="eyJjbGFpbSI6IHsidHlwZSI6ICJkb21haW4iLCAicm9sZSI6ICJ1c2VyOk", ts="1467851106", nonce="YTcdzC"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

To nest quotes inside a string, you should use single quotes. Otherwise, it is incorrect syntax.

As for the problem itself, this is the perfect case where you can use the `split` function to break the string into multiple components. Here it looks like you have three parameters, each separated by a comma.

Arrays in JavaScript are zero indexed, so to find the value for `ts`, we take the 2nd element of the array (indexed 1);

We are mainly looking for the digits here, so we can call the `replace` function to eliminate all non-digit characters (regex \D)

Convert it to a number with `+` or `parseInt`. We can now reset the 2nd element to have our new value.

All that's left is to convert to a string again, where we do the reverse of split, `join`.

Please take a look at this snippet

```js
var string = "id='eyJjbGFpbSI6IHsidHlwZSI6ICJkb21haW4iLCAicm9sZSI6ICJ1c2VyOk', ts='1467847506', nonce='YTcdzC'";

var components = string.split(',');
var ts = components[1];
var num = ts.replace(/\D/g, '');
var newNum = +(num) + 3600;
components[1] = "ts='" + newNum + "'"; 
string = components.join(', ');
console.log(string);
```